# How can I get the current value of a sequence in MonedDB?

Tags: sql, monetdb

For example, in PostgreSQL I can write the following lines to increment the sequence and to get the current value:

```
SELECT nextval('sequence');
SELECT currval('sequence');
```

In MonetDB I know how to write the first line:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR "sequence";
```

How can I write the second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_value_for`. Here is an example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "seq1" AS INTEGER START WITH 42;
SELECT next_value_for('sys','seq1'); -- returns 42 and increments seq1
SELECT get_value_for('sys','seq1');  -- returns 43
SELECT get_value_for('sys','seq1');  -- returns 43 again
```

Note the different quotes around `seq1`, this is required. Also, you need the pass your schema name to the functions. In this case it is `sys`.